# poedit string too long error

Tags: wordpress, poedit

I have an error 'String too long' when trying to scan my Wordpress plugin for translation. 
I have been over my plugin with a fine tooth comb but there are no mistakes in my translatable strings and they are all quite short. 
I have also looked for any clues in the documentation and forums as to what this error pertains to but so far with no luck.
Does anybody know what this error means?

[image: screenshot]

Many thanks

Comment: It's kind of hard to answer you when you don't even say what the exact error is (neither Poedit nor GNU gettext source code contain the string 'String too long'...) and don't show the relevant code. My guess would be some unterminated string in the PHP code.

Comment: I only have two files with translatable strings. I have checked, double checked and triple checked and they are correct. I have also checked against another plugin which doesn't get this error and has virtually identical structure and output but still I get the error on this one and not the other.

Comment: Really, it's impossible to guess what's going on if I cannot reproduce it. Can you please email me at help@poedit.net and send me a ZIP archive of the theme/plugin/whatever PHP code (with instructions on what to do with it in the latter case)? Sounds like a bug somewhere to me (at the very least, in usefulness of the message), but I need to reproduce it before I can fix it. TIA!